# Android SDK Manager and Emulator image not working in Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

I downloaded Android Studio bundle for mac and made a clean install. When it installed it downloaded tools and repositories and an Lollipop 21 x86 image. There are two problems I am facing:

1. Android SDK manager is not opening in Android Studio. The button does nothing and no window comes up. I dont know what to do in this. Android Studio downloaded Tools and everything when it installed and thats it I cannot download anything else now. When I run android sdk from terminal. It gives this error:

> Dhruvs-Mac-mini:tools dhruvsuri$ ./android
>
> ./android: line 30: dirname: command not found
>
> ./android: line 33: basename: command not found
>
> ./android: line 40: dirname: command not found
>
> ./android: line 44: dirname: command not found
>
> ./android: line 48: basename: command not found
>
> : can't find sdkmanager.jar

When I checked the User and Groups section in System Preferences it shows I am the admin.

2. The image emulator does not run. It is giving a strange error like this:

> /Users/dhruvsuri/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none
>   -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86
>
> sh: file: command not found
>
> sh: grep: command not found
>
> PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS.

Please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: I got it after days of trouble. The bash_profile file of my mac was corrupted . Thats why nothing was working. If anyone having same trouble You must  add sdk home directory in bash_profile file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I reset my the PATH variable in the .bash_profile file.
I did this by adding the two lines (using emacs, vi, etc).

PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH

Also run this to reload .bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

This fixed the problem for me.